# how to delete a record in transaction with sub-level using procedure in genexus

Tags: genexus

I tried to delete the records in Repair transaction using procedure but I'm getting an SQL error because it has a sub-level called Kind, here's the transaction structure:
[Repair Transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A79vM.png)

I also tried to delete the sub-level first before deleting the main-level but genexus can't detect that it's a transaction or transaction level.

How can I delete a record in transaction with sub-level using procedure in genexus?

[Here's the code snippet with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuSNh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second For Each must be "Transaction.Level"

Like this..

```
For Each Repair 
   For Each Repair.Kind
      Delete
   EndFor
   Delete
EndFor
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks @Eduardo